# OrderId data type is double in tick by tick datafeed

Tags: limit-order-book, tick-data, orderbook

I am going through multicast protocol for tick by tick data of national stock exchange(NSE, India) and the orders are uniquely identified by orderID and they have defined it to be a **double** datatype. The simple fact has baffled me because It is difficult to compare double or float for equality.

This makes it difficult to retrieve the data from a list in case of modification.

Any insights in this regard will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I would take a look at MTBT pcap files / datagrams to check the actual order numbers. Perhaps they use double but all order numbers are longs anyway.

Comment: thanks. It will try that.